# SQL - select a column based on fields in different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table users:  
    username  email                is_active
    ========  =====                =========
    john      john@something.com   1
    jane      janesomething.com    1
    bob       bobsomething.com     0

Table students:  
    username  class_number
    ========  =====
    john      1
    jane      2
    bob       1
```

How do I select the users (in my example, get john) who is active (is_active==1) and in class #1 (class_number==1)?

I tried

> SELECT * FROM users,students WHERE users.is_active=1 AND students.class_number=1

but that gave me "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 94371840 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 512 bytes) ".

Comment: You need a join condition in the `from` clause.  Learn about proper join syntax and the `on` clause.

Comment: You have no join, so it is doing a cartesian join by default.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a join condition. Without the query returns a cartesian product which is in most cases not what you want and could be a very expensive operation depending on the rowcounts.

For your case give this a try:

```
SELECT
   u.username

FROM
    users u JOIN students s ON u.username = s.username

WHERE
    u.is_active = 1
AND
    s.class_number=1
```

Answer (score 0):

In most dialects of SQL, you can do an inner join in either of two ways:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    users,
    students 
WHERE 
    users.username = students.username --JOIN CONDITION
    AND users.is_active=1 
    AND students.class_number=1
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    users 
    INNER JOIN students ON users.username = students.username --JOIN CONDITION
WHERE 
    users.is_active=1 
    AND students.class_number=1
```

If you are going to use the first syntax, you should look at the MySQL documentation for Joins (as of posting it was at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) and read the warnings. If you use the comma and you forget the join condition, then you will (as the comments above indicate) get a cartesian join with M*N records, where M is the number of records in the users table and N is the number of records in  the students table. (This is often called a cross join.) If you add the join condition to the WHERE clause, then you will get only those of the M*N records where the two columns have the same value.

The INNER JOIN syntax does the same thing, but it makes the fact that the `users.username = students.username` condition is a join condition explicit, and it will throw an error if you forget the join condition. The order of precedence is different between the comma and the INNER JOIN form, so usually you will want to use the INNER JOIN form and only the INNER JOIN form whenever you have outer joins as well.

If none of this is making sense to you, you should look at the Wikipedia article on Join (SQL).